# El Capitan- disabling csrutil

Tags: audio, plugins, osx-elcapitan

I installed El Capitan and have run into issues with loading audio units for Native Instruments. The workaround is to go into system recovery and type csrutil disable, which enable you to load an old version of the aulvaltool. I am booting off an external firewire drive, and everytime i boot into system recovery and try to use the command, it replies "command not found". I tried specifying the volume/csr/bin to no avail. Any ideas?

I am not a programmer- I just back everything up, and if I crash the drive, I just reinstall and start over..

Any help would be appreciated. Also if anyone has downloaded the new 10.11.1 beta, curious if it fixes this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: is el capitan installed on the external and a different version of OS X installed on an internal HD? my guess is your recovery partition doesn't have csrutil

Comment: please accept my reply since it's working on all the systems I applied it.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these step by step instructions:

- reboot
- as you hear the Apple Chime press COMMAND+R
- you will be in the Recovery mode
- from the upper MENU select Terminal
- you're booting from your internal drive recovery mode, so:
   A) el capitan is on your internal drive
        • type /usr/bin/csrutil disable
   B) el capitan is on your external drive
        • type /Volumes/TYPE_THE_EXTERNAL_DRIVE_NAME/usr/bin/csrutil disable

And you're done. Then you probably know how to proceed from the NI forum.